# How to do a left join in Core Data?

Tags: core-data, nspredicate

In my iOS messaging app, I'd like to display a list of the newest messages a user have with his interlocutors. In other words, this view is an overview of all chats.

I found [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group) for an SQL query that I've tried on the sqlite file:

```
SELECT m1.* FROM ZMMESSAGE m1 LEFT JOIN ZMMESSAGE m2 
ON (m1.ZINTERLOCUTORUSERNAME = m2.ZINTERLOCUTORUSERNAME AND m1.ZSENTAT < m2.ZSENTAT) 
WHERE m2.ZSENTAT IS NULL;
```

The query gives me the expected records, but how can I make an NSFetctRequest that does the same?

My entitiy is as follows:

[image]

Comment: Can you add the definition of the Core Data entities, attributes and relationships to your question?

Comment: I doubt that you can translate that query into a fetch request (but I may be wrong). - But wouldn't it make more sense to define a separate *User* entity (with name and imageid attributes) and a (one-to-many?) relationship from *User* to *Message*?

Comment: @MartinR I could, but would that help?

Comment: Fetching the latest message for each user should be possible (if that is what you need)